# Can I send variable to a text constant in Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have a file where I store my global constants. This is my file:

```
module.exports = {
    PORT: process.env.PORT || 4000,
    SERVER: "http://localhost:4200",
    FAIL_RESULT: "NOK",
    SUCCESSFUL_RESULT: "OK",

    // NEW VARIABLE
    MESSAGE: `Hi, ${name}`,
};
```

I want to create that new constant, but I need to send the name to show it later.

How can I make this?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest that you need to re-think your design - you said you have a file where you store your global constants, but if it changes, it's not a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getter property to get that:

```js
module.exports = {
    PORT: process.env.PORT || 4000,       
    SERVER: "http://localhost:4200",
    FAIL_RESULT: "NOK",
    SUCCESSFUL_RESULT: "OK",
    NAME: null ?? 'no name',
    // NEW VARIABLE
    get MESSAGE () { return `Hi, ${this.NAME}`},
};

console.log(obj.MESSAGE);
obj.NAME = 'Test Name';
console.log(obj.MESSAGE);
```

You should check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for more details.